# Counting the occurence of a specific variable in multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, count, multiple-columns

I would greatly apreciate any of you brilliant coders out there could help me with this. My coding expertise in mysql/php is limited but I am stubborn.

So far:
This successful query below gives the number of employees that have 'severe' in only one column 'rsmed' for the business named 'zmon', I now need to count 'severe' from multiple columns for the business 'zmon':

```
$host="localhost";
$username="user"; 
$password="pass";
$db_name="dbase";
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forearm WHERE business='zmon' AND rsmed = 'severe' "; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "There are ". $row['COUNT(*)'] ." employees severe in rsmed.";
}
```

I am stuck here: 
I need to count the number of 'severes' in multiple columns (rslat, rsmed, rscentral, rselbow) in the table named 'forearm' for the business named zmon.

So, column business contains a name of a business. 
The same business can have multiple rows each corresponding to different employees of theirs.
The other columns (rslat, rsmed, rscentral, rselbow) contain any of 4 variables: Not significant, low, medium, high and severe.

I hope that is enough information for you.

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate the query to use `SUM(criteria)` or `SUM(IF(condition, 1, 0))` to count each column individually.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(rslat = 'severe') as rslat_count,
    SUM(rselbow = 'severe') as rselbow_count,
    SUM(rsmed = 'severe') as rsmed_count,
    SUM(rscentral = 'severe') as rscentral_count
FROM forearm
WHERE business='zmon'
```

Data:

```
| id | business |  rslat | rselbow |  rsmed | rscentral |
|----|----------|--------|---------|--------|-----------|
|  1 |     zmon | severe |  severe | severe |      good |
|  2 |     zmon | severe |  severe |   good |      good |
|  3 |     zmon |   good |  severe |   good |      good |
|  4 |     zmon | severe |  severe |   good |      good |
```

Result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/093bd/2

```
| rslat_count | rselbow_count | rsmed_count | rscentral_count |
|-------------|---------------|-------------|-----------------|
|           3 |             4 |           1 |               0 |
```

Then you can display the results in php using

```
$sentence = 'There are %d employees severe in %s';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf($sentence, $row['rslat_count'], 'rslat');
    printf($sentence, $row['rselbow_count'], 'rselbow');
    printf($sentence, $row['rsmed_count'], 'rsmed');
    printf($sentence, $row['rscentral_count'], 'rscentral');
}
```

---

**UPDATED**

To get the derived total of the individual columns, you just need to add them up.

```
SELECT 
   SUM(counts.rslat_count + counts.rselbow_count + counts.rsmed_count + counts.rscentral_count) as severe_total,
   counts.rslat_count,
   counts.rselbow_count,
   counts.rsmed_count,
   counts.rscentral_count
FROM (
   SELECT 
      SUM(rslat = 'severe') as rslat_count,
      SUM(rselbow = 'severe') as rselbow_count,
      SUM(rsmed = 'severe') as rsmed_count,
      SUM(rscentral = 'severe') as rscentral_count
   FROM forearm
   WHERE business='zmon'
) AS counts
```

Result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/093bd/10

```
| severe_total | rslat_count | rselbow_count | rsmed_count | rscentral_count |
|--------------|-------------|---------------|-------------|-----------------|
|            8 |           3 |             4 |           1 |               0 |
```

Then display the severe total

```
$sentence = 'There are %d employees severe in %s';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf($sentence, $row['rslat_count'], 'rslat');
    printf($sentence, $row['rselbow_count'], 'rselbow');
    printf($sentence, $row['rsmed_count'], 'rsmed');
    printf($sentence, $row['rscentral_count'], 'rscentral');
    echo 'business in ' . $row['severe_total'] . ' severe conditions';
}
```

Comment: If you're looking to obtain counts on all of the statuses, a different query can be used for them as well.

Comment: Thanks to you. I realise now that my question was incompletely expressed. I need to total up the number of severes in table forearm.

Comment: @Paul Simple adjustment - updated, though you could also total the individual columns via PHP to display each with a total.

Answer (score 2):

If you are counting how many 'severes' are in the different columns (rslat, rsmed, rscentral, rselbow) you can try modifying your query to something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS employee_count, "rsmed" AS rtype 
FROM forearm WHERE business='zmon' AND rsmed = 'severe'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) AS employee_count, "rslat" AS rtype 
FROM forearm WHERE business='zmon' AND rslat = 'severe'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) AS employee_count, "rscentral" AS rtype 
FROM forearm WHERE business='zmon' AND rscentral = 'severe'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) AS employee_count, "rselbow" AS rtype 
FROM forearm WHERE business='zmon' AND rselbow = 'severe'
```

Then you can now write your loop like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "There are {$row['employee_count']} employees severe in {$row['rtype']}.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$username="user"; 
$password="pass";
$db_name="dbase";

$conn = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 

mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forearm WHERE business='zmon' AND rsmed = 'severe' "; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if($result){

  // Return the number of rows in result set

  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

  printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
  // Free result set

  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }

mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```

Comment: Thank you. This threw up an error. I think it it is in the msql/msqli department of confusion. Cheers, Paul